# Angular 2 and rxjs subject in service isn't being update on component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, subject

Hi to all and thanks for your help in advance...
I'm building an app and I want to have a service that is used to handle some configurations and it's shared by different modules.
I really don't know if this is the best approach, but I'm using this since angularJS.

*Config Service*

```
sidebarCompress: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
public sidebarCompressed: Observable<boolean> = this.sidebarCompress.asObservable();

constructor() {}

compressSidebar(val: boolean = false) {
    this.sidebarCompress.next(val);
    // this is firing when used
    console.log('changed on service');
}
```

*Sidebar component*

```
constructor(
    private conf: ConfigService,
) {
    conf.sidebarCompressed.subscribe(
        sidebarCompressed => {
            // this is not firing
            console.log('changed on sidebar component');
    });
}
```

*any other component*

```
constructor(
    private conf: ConfigService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // The idea is to use it in a fn (not always on init)
    this.conf.compressSidebar(true);
}
```

So, the Sidebar component subscription is not working, anyone knows what I am doing wrong here or if I should take a different approach!?

Again, Many thanks.

Comment: Where do you provide the `ConfigService`?

Comment: The `ConfigService` is provided in each module.
In this case, I have the module where I have the `SidebarComponent` and a lazy loaded Module called with the component that's trying to compress the sidebar. 
Both modules have the `ConfigService` provided...

I have it provided in the `app.module` as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide a service in `@NgModule()`, you get a single instance for the whole application, except when you also provide it in a `@Component()` or in `@NgModule()` of a lazy loaded module.

Providers provided in `@NgModule()` are hoisted into the applications root injector where the import order of modules matters, and modules listed later in `imports: []` override previous modules providers if the provider keys match. Providers added in `AppModule`s `@NgModule()` directly override providers of imported modules.

Lazy loaded modules get their own "root scope", which is a child injector of the application root injector.

I assume your problem is caused by providing the service in a non-lazy-loaded **and** lazy loaded module, which results in 2 instances.

Components or services that inject this module get either the instance from the application root, if they are part of modules that are non-lazy-loaded, or from the lazy loaded module when they are part of the lazy loaded module.

As solution, remove the provider from the lazy loaded module.
You can also implement `forRoot()` and import `MyLazyLoadedModule.forRoot()` in the `AppModule` to get the service of the lazy loaded module into the applications root injector and to avoid duplicate service instances.